# Can I use juju for continuous deployment on centos?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, continuous-deployment

I want to verify that [juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/) is not only for Ubuntu.

I want to build a continuous deployment which would be as good as juju for centos.

I have Java server apps.

If anyone has any other suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juju is an evolving technology and continuous development is going on. Even though the code is free, but it is made to use on ubuntu. So, at this moment using juju on centos won't be a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

People have hacked up juju to deploy CentOS on clouds. This involves patching up of code. However it will be a pure-CentOS cloud i.e. it may not enable you to have multiple OSes in the same environment. For more details, kindly check the link below:

[Juju Deploying CentOS Clouds](http://f.souza.cc/2012/07/using-juju-to-orchestrate-centos-based.html)

Comment: Please don't link to external resources, as they might be removed or become unavailable at a later point. Instead provide to summarize it and post it here for future reference.